# Error when adding app icon (apple mach-o linker id error)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I am simply trying to add app icons to my project, so I dragged and dropped my Icons from a folder I created inside the project. When building, I get the error below. If I remove the icons, I get no error.

What does this mean? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Click on the "Linker command failed" error, see what exactly is causing it there.

Comment: `ld: 9 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Fixed by removing a linked binary with libaries